# How to Set ESVersion to 10 in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, jshint

In order to use optional catch binding, I need to use ES10. So I set Visual Studio Code to esversion: 10. However, the settings.json keeps giving me the Problem "Value is not accepted. Valid values: 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9."

JSHint docs specifically name esversion 10: see https://jshint.com/docs/options/

Does anyone know why esversion 10 is not accepted in VSCode, and even better, how to change that?

Settings.json file is at C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User, if you don't get to it via File>Preferences>Settings. Seach for "jshint" and it will give you a link to Edit in settings.json.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the JSHint extension for Visual Studio Code does not get up to date with every JSHint update. For example, if you write `"esversion": 10` (or even `"esversion": 15` !!!) in the settings.json, the line gets a warning, as you describe, but code like *optional catch binding* is now allowed! So, `"esversion": 10` is understood correctly, despite the warning.
Thus, one solution is to leave this warning in settings.json, but have JSHint working fine in every other file.

But, this is what I prefer (workaround, not solution):

In the settings.json file leave it `"esversion": 9` and when you happen to need the *optional catch binding* or some other es10 feature, put in the top of this specific file:

```
/* jshint esversion: 10 */
```

You need to type this extra line, but now, there are no errors anywhere. Plus, this way you can see when you use any recent features, which may be anavailable to some users.

Answer (score 0):

This also works for version 11

```
/*jshint esversion: 11 */
```

But do not forget to turn off the auto beautify. Because on my side it is always throwing an error when i do a save :-)

Then this

```
const foo = null ?? 'default string';
console.log(foo);
```

turns to that

```
const foo = null ? ? 'default string';
console.log(foo);
```

and in the end you will get an error like this

```
Expression expected.
```

All the best and code on